# Confusion about coefficients in Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I know that Laurent series expands a function *f(z)* around a point even if it is not analytic at that point and the coefficients in the series expansion are given by

$$a_n =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}$$

**The above formula is nothing but Cauchy's integral formula**. But in my text book it says we can apply Cauchy's integral formula only if the function *f(z)* is analytic on and inside the curve *C*. But we already know Laurent series is true even when it is not analytic at that point.

What am I missing here?

Laurent series is not necessarily analytic everywhere but Cauchy's formula needs it to analytic everywhere. Seems contradictory!!

Comment: I think to answer your question properly we need some details on what you call Cauchy Integration formula.

Comment: The above expression only evaluates $f$ on $C$. The integral formula just says that if $f$ is analytic on & inside then the negative coefficients are zero.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Cauchy's integral formula is one which we use to find value of a function anywhere inside a function $$f(c) =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-c)}$$

Comment: @Siddaram what assumption do you have on $f$ in your theorem?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Based on your comments I might have realized my mistake.

In Taylor series, using Cauchy's formula, if it is analytic at the point  the above coefficient a_n ends up being $$ \frac{f'(z)}{n!} $$ But in Laurent Series it just remains a_n if it is not analytic. Am I right?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent my whole question is we should use $$a_n= \frac{f'(z_0)}{n!} $$ only when the function is analytic at point of expansion. If it is not analytic the coefficient is just $$a_n =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$$ because we can't use Cauchy's formula in that case